# If a number repeats, only show it once

Tags: xslt, repeat

Hi if I have the following XML input file

```
<data>
<group id= "1">
<phrase>Doc1</phrase>
<document refid ="3"/>
<document refid ="5"/>
<document refid= "1"/>
</group>
<group id= "2">
 <phrase>Doc2</phrase>
<document refid ="2"/>
<document refid ="3"/>
<document refid= "6"/>
</group>
  <group id= "3">
 <phrase>Doc3</phrase>
<document refid ="2"/>
<document refid ="3"/>
<document refid= "4"/>
</group>
</data>
```

Is it possible to have an output which checks each group to see if the document "refid" number was not displayed in the previous groups? For example I would like my output as

```
<data>
 <group id= "1">
 <phrase>Doc1</phrase>
<document refid ="3"/>
<document refid ="5"/>
<document refid= "1"/>
</group>
<group id= "2">
 <phrase>Doc2</phrase>
<document refid ="2"/>
<document refid= "6"/>
</group>
  <group id= "3">
 <phrase>Doc3</phrase>
<document refid= "4"/>
</group>
</data>
```

I am trying to do this in XSLT 1.0.
I hope this explains the question clearly. I would really appreciate your help. 
Thank you

Comment: Don't use `version="1.1"`. It is an obsolete version of XSLT. See http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xslt#obsolete.

Comment: @mzjn oh yeah i have 1.0. sorry that was a typo. thanks though

Comment: The placement of `<p>` inside the $total for-each loop is in vain. It just makes it harder for you to extract the values (forcing you to use the node-set() extension), and then the `<p>` elements are thrown away anyway because all you use from $total is the text() nodes, not elements. Even if you use node-set(), you need `node-set($total)/text()`, not `node-set($total/text())` - you can only apply `/text()` (the child axis) to the *result* of node-set(), not to a result tree fragment.

Comment: I would like to make some positive suggestions, but the input XML above is too far from matching the input expected by the stylesheet you posted. E.g. document elements have no title or @refid.

Comment: @LarsH thats not actually not my original input XML file. I had pasted that before 'jkbr' asked me for my original XSLT file. My XML file is pretty big and has lot more stuff.

Comment: @user: yeah, I understood that.

Comment: The overuse of `xsl:for-each` (nested!?) should be replaced with `xsl:apply-templates` to make the whole transform much readable and reusable. If your input is big, try to cut it and display the parts meaningful to this question.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is short and simple and one of the most efficient as it uses keys (Muenchian grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an efficient and short solution, using keys [(Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html))**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kDocById" match="document" use="@refid"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "@*
            |
             node()[not(self::document)]
            |
             document
                  [generate-id()
                  =
                  generate-id(key('kDocById', @refid)[1])
                  ]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (reflecting the latest refinement made in a comment by the OP):

```
<data>
    <group id= "1">
        <phrase>Doc1</phrase>
        <document refid ="3"/>
        <document refid ="5"/>
        <document refid= "1"/>
    </group>
    <group id= "2">
        <phrase>Doc2</phrase>
        <document refid ="2"/>
        <document refid ="3"/>
        <document refid= "6"/>
    </group>
    <group id= "3">
        <phrase>Doc3</phrase>
        <document refid ="2"/>
        <document refid ="3"/>
        <document refid= "4"/>
    </group>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<data>
   <group id="1">
      <phrase>Doc1</phrase>
      <document refid="3"/>
      <document refid="5"/>
      <document refid="1"/>
   </group>
   <group id="2">
      <phrase>Doc2</phrase>
      <document refid="2"/>
      <document refid="6"/>
   </group>
   <group id="3">
      <phrase>Doc3</phrase>
      <document refid="4"/>
   </group>
</data>
```

Comment: OMG Thankyou so much!!! That did the trick. I really really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just 1 more question. If my input was changed to this format 

 </group>
    <group id= "2">
    <phrase>Doc1</phrase>
        <document refid ="2"/>
        <document refid ="3"/>
        <document refid= "6"/>
    </group>
    <group id= "3">
     <phrase>Doc2</phrase>
        <document refid ="2"/>
        <document refid ="3"/>
        <document refid= "4"/>
    </group>
How do i get DOc1 and Doc 2 to show as well? Is it possible for you to edit the solution you sent me so that I get Doc1 and Doc2 printed as well? Thank you!

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Its great to have awesome contributors like you to help us newbies. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @user807496: One way of saying "Thank you" (this is the official way here at SO) is to accept the best answer. To do so, click on the check-mark next to the answer. I am glad my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

**`$ cat style.xsl`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!--
    This templates matches the document elements with a @refid that has already been used
    in on of the previous groups. They are simply ignored.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="document[../preceding-sibling::group/document/@refid = current()/@refid]" />


    <!--
    Everything else gets copied to the output.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**`$ xsltproc style.xsl input.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <group id="1">
        <document refid="3"/>
        <document refid="5"/>
        <document refid="1"/>
    </group>
    <group id="2">
        <document refid="2"/>

        <document refid="6"/>
    </group>
    <group id="3">


        <document refid="4"/>
    </group>
</data>
```

**Edit:** to incorporate it into your stylesheet, try to change the `for-each` at line 49 to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document[not(../preceding-sibling::group/document/@refid = current()/@refid)]">
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help but I actually have  <xsl:template match="/"> on top on my XSLT file and if I try to place the lines of code you gave me for template-match, it shows me the error: Element must only be used at top level of stylesheet
Is it possible to manipulate this? I cant remove <xsl:template match="/"> from my original XSLT since I need it for somethign else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a way I can mail you or something? its kinda big and wont be able to display it properly here in the comment section

Comment: i pasted my XSLT file. I tried pasting my XML file but it wasnt coming out properly at all. I hope this helps you understand my problem

Comment: You just want me to add <xsl:for-each select="document[not(../preceding-sibling::group/document/@refid = current()/@refid)]">
 to line 49 to my stylesheet? Coz this doesnt work :( What about the template-match you wrote in your answer. Do I need to manipulate that and paste it somewhere in the stylesheet too?

Comment: You can use the whole stylesheet that I've posted as a standalone one to preprocess the XML. But if you want to incorporate it into your existing stylesheet, then you need to replace `<xsl:for-each select="document">` on line 49 with the tag from the bottom of my answer. It's because the only important part from my stylesheet is the XPath expression.

Comment: somehow its not working but I will play around with it. THank you so much for your help and the head start. I really appreciate it :)